# Xcode UI Testing - Timestamped Event Matching Error

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

We are getting this error when recording a UI test.  At this point the recorder stops recording code.  What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: Simples answer to your question is that it doens't find the item you clicked in. How to fix this, it's what I'm search for as well.

Comment: Xcode 8 still exists, I think it's a bug

Comment: This work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616891/timestamped-event-matching-error-failed-to-find-matching-element/39121303#39121303

Answer (score 9):

What this means is that when you click on an item, Xcode can't figure what element it was. Not sure if it's a bug or not.

In my case I was clicking on a table view cell, and was getting this. The way I got around it was adding these lines:

```
let cells = app.tables.cells
cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
```

Get the reference of the table cells, and for the tap yourself on the view. Of course this is a case by case solution, but it should help you carry on.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding your storyboard to the UI tests target membership.

Click the storyboard, then on the right click file inspector, then scroll down to target membership and click UI tests.

Comment: My solution to my first UI Tests in Xcode 9, thanks!

Comment: This did not help me.