# Timestamped Event Matching Error: Failed to find matching element

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to generate a UItest in Xcode. When I try to swipe UIview I get 
an error:

```
Timestamped Event Matching Error: Failed to find matching element
```

[error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGlWq.png)

[image]

This also happens if I try to tap UIView.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: i try to swipe or tap on UIview that suppose to do something (has gesture reconizer) but when i do the gesture this error happens.
the only way i mannged to make it work is with queries but its realy complicated and im sure that there is another way

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should verify that the 'Accessibility' option is enabled for the UIView object you are swiping from, for example:

[image]

Comment: Turning Accessibility on for a WebView made my tests fail when resolving text in the WebView. Turning Accessibility OFF for the UIView hosting the WebView made the tests succeed. So beware.

Comment: As another point to make it work for me I had to give it a label

Comment: I found this post helpful in for using `fastlane` to take screenshots of a tableView. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331154/4475605

Comment: Where is this? How do I set this?

Comment: @CoryMcAboy you can set it from code for your custom view: ```isAccessibilityElement = true```

Answer (score 20):

Usually this issue is observed when the parent element of the element yo want to record is set to `isAccessibilityElement = true`. In general, you have to have the parent element set to false to access the child element.

For example: if you have a `UILabel` inside a view, the accessibility should be set to false for the view and set to true for the `UILabel`.

Comment: This was exactly reproducable. As you said it does not work of the parent element is set to isAccessibilityElement = true ! After I switched it back to false it worked again.

Answer (score 2):

For recording a new test, I don't think there's a solution yet. But, if you use an extension forcing tap with a test that already exists, works.

Example of use:

```
extension XCUIElement {

    func forceTapElement() {
        if self.hittable {
            self.tap()
        }
        else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0))
            coordinate.tap()
        }  
    }
}

func testSomethingWithCells() {

   let app = XCUIApplication()
   let cells = app.tables.cells
   sleep(1)
   cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).forceTapElement()
}
```

You can check the original post here:

[Xcode UI test - UI Testing Failure - Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) when tap on Search field "Cancel' button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422681/xcode-ui-test-ui-testing-failure-failed-to-scroll-to-visible-by-ax-action)

Comment: elementBoundByIndex' has been renamed to 'element(boundBy:)', Eg:         cells.element(boundBy: 0).tap()

Answer (score 2):

I've been occasionally running into this problem.  Delete the app's directory from DerivedData seems to help.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 9.3, where this is apparently still a problem, what I did was:

- Quit Xcode
- Reset the Simulator's settings (Hardware -> Erase all
  contents and settings)
- Quit the Simulator
- Delete the derived data for the current app
- Restart Xcode
- Try recording again - it worked this time for me.

Comment: I have provided the identifier as "skipButton" for a button and on identifying button , it always use to fails, I am identifying the button as app.buttons["skipButton'] , appreciate your help

Comment: These steps did not work for me. In fact, widgets that were not previously affected by the problem became affected.

Comment: why does this have no content?

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for myself was to identify the object differently.
In Xcode 8 I was able to use the following:

```
XCUIApplication().tables.cells["Camera Roll"].buttons["Camera Roll"].tap()
```

With Xcode 9 I got the error mentioned in this question.  Ended up using the following, which worked (al beit more flakey than the original option)

```
XCUIApplication().cells.element(boundBy: 1).tap()
```

Comment: @Developer in your test function

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have Accessibility enabled for the element, you have to make sure that it has a **unique** accessibility identifier. In my case, I had copied & pasted a `UISwitch` and assigned a different outlet to it, but it kept the same accessibility ID as the original one.